# Magento SOAP API V2 calls not working for Private Sales Store (Authorization plugin used)

Tags: magento-1.9

FACTS:

I am not very good at magento but have some experience working with API's using PHP.

TARGET:

What I actually want to do is

1. Download magento customer orders in our order system
2. Process the orders
3. Upload tracking code back to magento
4. Update magento products level based on the values fetched from our local Stock System running on a different server

ENVIRONMENT:

I am using a Login Plugin to make the store private so only customers with an account can access it.

PROBLEM:

IF 'AUTHENTICATION' PLUGIN IS DISABLED EVERYTHING WORKS FINE. BUT WHEN PLUGIN IS ENABLED STEP 3 AND 4 STOP WORKING.

ERROR SAMPLE:

Magento SOAP API V2 calls result in

SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => looks like we got no XML document, when used for Private Sales store. I am able to login using API a/c,fetch orders but calls to update stock / upload tracking etc fail.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

Login Successful [0a254c064fa033859bc75db94]

Request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateRequestParam>sessionId>0a254c064fa033859bc75db94</sessionId><productId>1</productId><data><qty>100</qty><is_in_stock>1</is_in_stock></data></ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateRequestParam></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Result:

SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => looks like we got no XML document [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /var/www/vhosts/XXX/magentoAPI/stock.php [line:protected] => 31 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /var/www/vhosts/XXX/magentoAPI/stock.php [line] => 31 [function] => __call [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate [1] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sessionId] => 0a254c064fa033859bc75db94 [productId] => 1587 [data] => Array ( [qty] => 1000 [is_in_stock] => 1 ) ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /var/www/vhosts/XXX/magentoAPI/stock.php [line] => 31 [function] => catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sessionId] => 0a254c064fa033859bc75db94  [productId] => 1587 [data] => Array ( [qty] => 1000 [is_in_stock] => 1 ) ) ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => looks like we got no XML document [faultcode] => Client [faultcodens] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ )